# How to I check if every row in a 2D array has at least 2 elements?

Tags: python, currency, new-operator

Right now every element has only one element:

```
dots_list = [ [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21] ]
```

How would I break out of a while loop based on the condition of every element having at least 2 elements, where the second element is a dot.

```
dots_list = [ [1 . . . .],[2 ..],[3 . .],[4 .],[5 .],(...), [20 . .], [21 . ] ]
```

The total number of dots isn't important as it can have an infinite number of them. The important part is how to end the loop when all numbers in the list have at least one dot.

You can ignore most of the code as I have that part working, not sure on the loop condition though.

```
pd = [ #This is the visual of the pyramid

[                 1                    ], #[0][0]  row and total col# ex [2][1] = 5
[              2,    3                 ], #[1][1]
[            4,   5,    6,             ], #[2][2]
[         7,   8,    9,   10,          ], #[3][3]
[      11,  12,   13,  14,   15,       ], #[4][4]
[    16,  17,   18,  19,  20,    21,   ], #[5][5]

]

x = 0 # represents left and right direction in pd -- adding goes right, subtracting goes left
y = 5 # represents up and down direction in pd -- adding goes down, subtracting goes up

lower_bound = 1 #used as lower bound in dice selection
upper_bound = 4 #used as upper bound in dice selection

move_counter = 0 #used to count the total number of moves made in game

print("Starting position: ",pd[y][x])  # The starting position used for debugging
start_position = pd[y][x] # The starting point of the game [y][x] up/down y, left/right x

#     ----  loop begin ----
#while()


random_roll = random.randint(lower_bound, upper_bound) # Randomly selects a number from 1 to 4 to be used as fair die roll
print("Random Roll: " ,random_roll)
#--------------------------------pd bounds checking-------------------------------------------
if random_roll == 1  and (pd[y][x]) != 2 \
        and (pd[y][x]) != 4 and (pd[y][x]) != 11 and (pd[y][x]) != 16:
   #--------------------------------pd bounds checking-------------------------------------------

    print('upper left')
   # print('x: ', x, 'y:', y)

    if pd[y][x] == 1:
        print('Invalid Direction --  Move Count Increased')
        move_counter += 1
    else:
        new_pos = pd[y-1][x-1]
        y-=1
        x-=1
        #print('x: ', x, 'y:', y)
        print('new pos: ' , new_pos)
        start_position = new_pos
        print('st pos', start_position)

        move_counter += 1

#--------------------------------pd bounds checking-------------------------------------------
elif random_roll == 2  and (pd[y][x]) != 3 \
        and (pd[y][x]) != 6 and (pd[y][x]) != 10 and (pd[y][x]) != 15 and (pd[y][x]) != 21:
    # --------------------------------pd bounds checking-------------------------------------------
    print('upper right')
    #print('x: ', x, 'y:', y)

    if pd[y][x] == 1:
        print('Invalid Direction --  Move Count Increased')
        move_counter += 1
    else:
        new_pos = pd[y-1][x]
        y-=1
        x+=1
       # print('x: ', x, 'y:', y)
        print('new pos: ' , new_pos)
        start_position = new_pos
        print('st pos', start_position)
        move_counter += 1


#--------------------------------pd bounds checking-------------------------------------------
elif random_roll == 3 and (pd[y][x]) != 16 and (pd[y][x]) != 17 \
        and (pd[y][x]) != 18 and (pd[y][x]) != 19 and (pd[y][x]) != 20 and (pd[y][x]) != 21:
# --------------------------------pd bounds checking-------------------------------------------
    print(' down left')

    #print('x: ', x, 'y:', y)
    new_pos = pd[y+1][x]
    x-=1
    y+=1
   # print('x: ', x,  'y:' , y)
    print('new pos: ' , new_pos)
    start_position = new_pos
    print('st pos', start_position)
    move_counter += 1

#--------------------------------pd bounds checking-------------------------------------------
elif random_roll == 4 and (pd[y][x]) != 16 and (pd[y][x]) != 17 \
        and (pd[y][x]) != 18 and (pd[y][x]) != 19 and (pd[y][x]) != 20 and (pd[y][x]) != 21 :
# --------------------------------pd bounds checking-------------------------------------------
    print('down right')

   # print('x: ', x, 'y:', y)
    new_pos = pd[y+1][x+1]
    x+=1
    y+=1

   # print('x: ', x, 'y:', y)
    print('new pos: ' , new_pos)
    start_position = new_pos
    print('st pos', start_position)
    move_counter += 1

else:
    print('Invalid Direction --  Move Count Increased')
    start_position = pd[y][x]
    print('st pos', start_position)
    move_counter += 1

# ---- loop end ----
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `any` function and iterate over the elements of your list with a comprehension that checks if the length of any element is less than 2. If any element is shorter than 2 then the loop will continue, once all elements have length at least 2, the loop will stop.

For example:

```
while any(len(x) < 2 for x in pd):
    # do stuff
```

Where `pd` is your 2d list from your example.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot more sense. I'm still rather new to stack overflow so I'm not sure about follow up questions. But, say I meet the condition in game where it's time to add a dot (I made a valid move to a number and now that number has been visited: once, twice, however many times) would it be better to append to the dots_list at that specific index or is there a way to add the dot via other insert methods?

Comment: @Code_Cuts I'm not sure I understand your question fully, but using `append` is a fine way to add to a list. If you plan to insert more than one value you can use `extend` or list concatenation `+=`. Does that help?

Comment: To clarify more I was asking if list = [ [0] , [1] ]  would using  list[0].append('*') now make the first sublist element containt 2 elements like [ [0 *] , [1] ]. Other than that thank you for the response it makes much more sense now.

Comment: well, now I have a new problem, with the added while loop I keep getting the list out of bound errors it has to do with the X and Y coordinate which worked fine before the change.

Comment: @Code_Cuts I'd suggest cleaning up the bounds checking to be more dynamic. You could do something like: `if y + dy > 0 and y + dy < len(pd) and x + dx > 0 and x + dx < len(pd[y + dy])`. Where `dy` and `dx` are either 1 or -1. Note that the order here is important, you have to check the `y` values first or you'll get an out of bounds error.